# How long does a session[] retain data?

Tags: asp.net, session, session-variables

I am trying to use a session but when i need the value back its null?

My website starts off with a login where i put the user name into a Session.

```
Session["userName"] = login.UserName;
```

Then the website is redirected to a new page.

```
return RedirectToAction("Choice", new { token = token });
```

after witch i use a link to move to my next page.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Download", "Download", new {token = Model.Token})
```

Where i direct my code to a action result in the Home controller, the same controller i have my login function.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Download", "DownloadFile", new { fileid = item.Key, token = Model.Token, platform = "windows", filename = item.Value }, new {@class = "DownloadLink" } )
```

Where i try call up my session value again.

```
formMobiApi.GetFile(token, fileid, platform, filename, Session["userName"].ToString(), tasks, taskId, spreadSheetStatus);
```

Are any of these actions doing anything to make my session value null?

Can i use a session like this?

Comment: How are your sessions handled? Are they cookie based or inproc? What is your session timeout value in your web.config also?

Comment: I could not find any session timeouts in my web.Config, and i am unsure if my sessions are cookie based or inproc, how would i check?

Answer (score 16):

If you are not manually setting your session state in web.config then the defaults you **should** have are in-process (sessions are stored in the RAM of the web server) and timeout is 20 minutes - [see here for more information on session states](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

You can manually set your states in your web.config file with the following:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="20"></sessionState>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Now, onto your actual issue. I'm not exactly sure why your session isn't persisting and I can't feasibly find out as I don't have a copy of your code to debug. At a guess I'd say your `HttpContext` is different from when you initialized the session, to when you're requesting it and so your context key is different. Try changing

```
Session["userName"].ToString();
```

to

```
HttpContext.Current.Session["userName"].ToString();
```

This looks a little odd at first glance, as you're effectively doing the EXACT same thing. The difference comes down to if the current object doesn't have access to the `HttpContext` you need to explicitly define which context to read from.

Having taken another look at the code you've provided, there's nothing out of the ordinary - this should work. I really am starting to believe this is an environment / configuration issue. If you're using **Form Authentication** then check your timeout in your web.config file. Also, if you're hosting in IIS (and not Visual Studio's web server - although you should check this too!) try deleting your application pool and recreating it.

Comment: You can also get/set the value in code with the Session.Timeout property, like:

Session.Timeout = 5;

Answer (score 0):

Your session variable is set up properly and it is being called properly to obtain the value.

The only thing left to debug is to actually see if **login.UserName** has an actually value. Because you might just be setting a session variable to null(**login.UserName**).

also try adding this to your web.config file if that doesn't work.

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="20" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" />
      </providers>
</sessionState>
```